# Where do questions about character standardisation belong?

Tags: discussion, questions

If I have a question about character representation and their standardisation, which of SE sites is appropriate?

E.g.:

> "What is the rationale behind having "minus sign" and "hyphen" encoded
>   as single character and having same representation?"

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a question about typographic history, which is certainly offtopic here (as it's not even remotely about computer *science*).

I am not aware of any site that deals with this. People in the [tex.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) may know the answer, though.